# Laravel-Lumen: How can i install the following package that is supported in laravel to a lumen project package that can helps in debugging api logs?

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

Hello i want to install the following package to my lumen project. This is a small package that can helps in debugging api logs.

[Package Link](https://github.com/aungwinthant/apilogger)

I have followed every step but unable to install it and use it in Lumen.
Also i have used this package: [Lara Support](https://github.com/irazasyed/larasupport)

I have added the service manually also migrated the database:
This is the following error that im reciveing:

[image]

[image]

**app.php**

```
$app->register(Irazasyed\Larasupport\Providers\ArtisanServiceProvider::class);
$app->register(AWT\Providers\ApiLogServiceProvider::class);
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/apilogs', 'AWT\Http\Controllers\ApiLogController@index')->name("apilogs.index");

Route::delete('/apilogs/delete', 'AWT\Http\Controllers\ApiLogController@delete')->name("apilogs.deletelogs");
```

If anyone would be kind to share a repo with this laravel package installed into a lumen test project would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since Lumen doesn't have Package Discovery you probably need to add manually the Service provider in you bootstrap.config file like this :

```
$app->register(AWT\Providers\ApiLogServiceProvider::class);
```

Do you have any errors to share so we can understand what is the problem ? Is the service provider not recognized at all ?

Comment: I have added the service manually also migrated the database. Now is giving me the following error when i try to navigate to the loggs dashboard route: Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::name()

Comment: I have modified the question for your consideration

Comment: hum... this package doesn't seem to support Lumen, only Laravel, so your first error here is that it uses a different Router class (which in Lumen doesn't have a name static function). You could override the router class to add this name function but this seems hacky and I fear you'll be stuck with another problem right after this.